# Life's Legos Lost

Tags: rhyme, knowledge, steganography

> Puzzles are fun don't you think
>   Good ones are quite hard to find
>   Perhaps you will like this one
>   Really, I'm ready to sink
>   This puzzle starts fairly simply
>   Look for the pieces that rhyme
>   I fear the foundation is slanted
>   Organized with a wink
>   An interesting set of trebles
>   Regardless, once you are done
>   Under this layer of mine
>   Hearken to what is put boldly
>   Gather these building blocks
>   Looking at how they're cemented
>   Organized for letting you run
>   Shorten yet further these pebbles
>   Realize this pattern vaguely
>   Listen, you'll find that it talks
>   Even while you're feeling thwarted
>   Proteins ensure you are able
>   Until you are placed in a box

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be related to:

> some kind of chemical compounds, perhaps something to do with DNA (reading the title)
>
>  Order the lines in groups of ones that rhyme (as suggested by the sixth line) we get:
>  **P**uzzles are fun don't you think
>  **R**eally, I'm ready to sink
>  **O**rganized with a wink
>
>  **G**ood ones are quite hard to find
>  **L**ook for the pieces that rhyme
>  **U**nder this layer of mine
>
>  **P**erhaps you will like this one
>  **R**egardless, once you are done
>  **O**rganized for letting you run
>
>  **T**his puzzle starts fairly simply
>  **H**earken to what is put boldly
>  **R**ealize this pattern vaguely
>
>  **I** fear the foundation is slanted
>  **L**ooking at how they're cemented
>  **E**ven while you're feeling thwarted
>
>  **A**n interesting set of trebles
>  **S**horten yet further these pebbles
>  **P**roteins ensure you are able
>
>  **G**ather these building blocks
>  **L**isten, you'll find that it talks
>  **U**ntil you are placed in a box
>  The first letters of these appear to be abbreviations for chemical compounds.

Thanks to Wu33o, who provided a link, we've got:

> PRO for proline, abbreviated to **P**
>  GLU for glutamic acid, abbreviated to **E**
>  THR for threonine, abbreviated to **T**
>  ILE for isoleucine, abbreviated to **I**
>  ASP for aspartic acid, abbreviated to **D**

Combining these letters in order of appearance we get:

> **PEPTIDE**

Comment: Use the letter codes from [this table](http://www.fao.org/docrep/004/Y2775E/y2775e0e.htm), change the order a bit, and you're there ;)

Comment: Knowledge tag suits perfectly! I couldn't have figured it out :) +1

Comment: This is correct, well done, that was incredibly quick.